# Python: conversion of byte string to structure with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I have to convert byte string to the structure with ctypes. This is the documentation:

```
The VIDEO_IMAGE format is composed of a fixed header followed by the data. The header is a C-like structure, with big-endian byte order and no alignment:

struct {
    unsigned int     magic_number = 0x5644454f;
    unsigned short   version;        // only version 1 is supported
    unsigned short   image_mode;     // Y8,Y16,....
    long     long    frame_number;   // the frame number (counter)
    int              width;          // the frame width in pixel (horizontal size)
    int              height          // the frame height in pixel (vertical size)
    unsigned short   endianness;     // 0-little-endian, 1-big-endian
    unsigned short   header_size;    // this header size in byte
    unsigned short   padding[2];     // 4 bytes of padding (for alignment)
} VIDEO_IMAGE_STRUCT;
```

This is was I am doing (I coped only header):

```
from ctypes import BigEndianStructure, c_int, c_uint, c_ushort, c_long, c_byte

class VideoImageData(BigEndianStructure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("magic_number", c_uint),
        ("version", c_ushort),
        ("image_mode", c_ushort),
        ("frame_number", c_long),
        ("width", c_int),
        ("heigth", c_int),
        ("endianness", c_ushort),
        ("header_size", c_ushort),
        ("padding", c_ushort)
    ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dstr = b'YATD\x02\x00@\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x08\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    s = VideoImageData.from_buffer(bytearray(dstr))
```

However, the results is not correct:

```
IN[1]: s.magic_number
Out[1]: 1497453636 (must be 1447314767)
In[2]: s.version
Out[2]: 512 (must be 1)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The 5th and 6th bytes are 2 and 0 which **is** 0x0200 (512). So the result is as expected for the version field.

Comment: The magic number is correct as well.  Your expectation is wrong and is VDEO not YATD.

Comment: The data bytes also look little-endian, not big-endian.  `\x02\x00` is more likely 2, not 512 if those bytes are also a ushort version for a VDEO structure.  Do you have a reference for your structure definition?

Comment: It looks like you are just referring to the wrong raw data structure.  You want one with VDEO not YATD.  Also `frame_number` should be `c_longlong` not `c_long` and `padding` should be `c_ushort * 2` for `unsigned short padding[2]`.